# How do I get Multiple (4) tables to display in one view when using asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, web-applications, view

Hi all I'm fairly new to the whole asp.net mvc thing but I'm picking it all up pretty quickly, one question I have though, is it possible to have multiple tables being populated from one database on a view? Is this what partial views are for? For example I'm trying to get a number of different checklists on one page. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes exactly you can use partial view for these.
for these you need to send all tables in a combine list and bind partial views separately.
use renderpartial for better performance

Comment: Many thanks for your advice, that's the only problem with self learning is your stuck if you don't get something :-)

Comment: just try to make habit in searching in google. more you search more you get the experience in how search in google

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty good at that but sometimes if you don't put in exactly the right combination of words it doesn't show you the answer that would have been most helpful :-) that and sometimes the results are that complicated you don't know where to start! Luckily I'm understanding more and more which I didn't think would happen at the start a week or two ago :-)

Comment: oh thats cool.u will get used to whenever you use it frequently:)